# How to mock all requests to a site with stub_request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rspec, mocking

I want to mock *all* requests to a given site in my rspec tests with stub_reuest ... not just the URL's I know about today. In particular, I want to raise an exception or timeout to simulate a REST service being offline or broken.

How do I match all URL's for just one site? How do I block any URL for a given host?

Comment: Is there a reason you ask and answer all your own questions?

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing that!

Comment: Of course, @engineersmnky ... to share knowledge! :-)  I searched for what I needed, and did not find a solution that matched the keywords I was looking for. So now, the next person who searches for this issue will hopeful find a simple, copy-and-paste solution!

Answer (score 8):

Use `:any` to match all methods, and a regular expression to match all URL's:

```
their_site = 'http://rest.example.com'
stub_request(:any, /#{their_site}.*/ ).to_raise(Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

or

```
their_site = 'https://rest.example.com:443/api'
stub_request(:any, %r[#{their_site}.*] ).to_timeout
```

or

```
stub_request(:any, %r[#{their_site}.*] )
  .to_return(status: 500, body: 'Sorry, mate.')
```

or

```
stub_request(:any, %r[#{their_site}.*] )
  .to_return(status: 404)
```

or

```
stub_request(:any, %r[#{their_site}.*] )
  .to_return(status: 200, 'We tried our best.')
```

If you want to break *all* external hits, you can do that with a regex:

```
stub_request(:any, /.*/ ).to_timeout
```

Comment: This is great, i am using it for `stub_command`: `let(:module_is_installed) do /\(Get-Module.*/ end`